# Oracle db unique constraint design consultant

Tags: database, oracle, conditional-statements, unique-constraint

I have 3 tables: A,B,C.
A consists of a column D.
B consists of columns E,F,G,H,I,J (PK is J).
C consists of foreign key K to table B.

now I need to have F,G,H unique, but if G is null then have F,H unique and I and E unique. (and G XOR I must be null).
is there a way I can do it in db and not programatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do this with unique indexes and the fact that `NULL` is ignored for a unique index.

First, create an index on F, G, and H:

```
create unique index idx_b_f_g_h on b(f, g, h)
```

This handles the "F, G, H unique" case.  To handle the "G is null, then F, H unique" do:

```
create unique index idx_b_f_h_j on b(f, h, (case when G is null then 0 else j end));
```

This replaces a non-NULL values of G with the primary key -- ensuring uniqueness.  It uses an arbitrary "constant" value when `G` is null.  (Note the constant should be of the same type as the primary key.)

To handle, I and E unique, you can also use a functional index.  I think you mean:

```
create unique index idx_b_i_e_j on b(coalesce(i, e));
```

You can handle the fact that `i` or `e` is `NULL` using a check constraint.